# React Native with M1 chip

Tags: react-native

It's been few months since M1 chip release, I have heard that M1 chip cannot build android app, is it true? I'm gonna get a MacBook next month, planning to get an Intel MacBook Pro 2020 but it's so rare and M1x is coming too.
So how was your experience with M1 chip? is there anything that Intel can and M1 can't?

Answer (score 0):

The Short answer is Yes, but you have to keep in mind that some apps, libraries, plugins might not work and need to wait for it to update to support the M1 chip.

take a look at this

https://amanhimself.dev/blog/setup-macbook-m1/

Answer (score 0):

I got an M1 Mac Mini last week and it built my Android release files fine. Actually it forced me to upgrade certain packages I was using in order to build, and the final release ended up significantly more performant.

Of course, for development you have to use a real Android device, but even that has not been great for me so far.